# Recognize text in image

Tags: image-processing, ocr

I have the following image and I want to extract the text on the axes. I used the following code:

```
HighlightImage[
  pic,   
  FindImageText[#, "Word", AcceptanceThreshold -> 0]&
]
```

[image: a single line plot with text as axis ticks]

No matter what I do, it just doesn't recognize all the text:

[image: same plot, but only some of the ticks were highlighted]

Any ideas what the problem could be?

Comment: Do you have a link to the original image?

Comment: https://d3fy651gv2fhd3.cloudfront.net/charts/euro-area-gdp-growth.png?s=eugnemuq&v=202204291011V20220312&d1=19970520